# Sort Records by Date and then color and aggregate the counts with lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming, lodash

I have an array of objects which i want to sort by Date and then by color and sum the occurrences using lodash

`InitialArray = [{"date":"2017-07-26","partner":"partner1","total":102,"occurrence":10},{"date":"2017-07-27","partner":"partner1","total":100,"occurrence":20},{"date":"2017-07-27","partner":"partner1","total":110,"occurrence":25},{"date":"2017-07-27","partner":"partner2","total":105,"occurrence":30}]`

I need it to be sorted by date and then by partner and aggregate the total and occurrence count for a given date.
So my final array needs to look like:

`FinalArray = [{"date":"2017-07-26","partner":"partner1","total":102,"occurrence":10},{"date":"2017-07-27","partner":"partner1","total":210,"occurrence":45},{"date":"2017-07-27","partner":"partner2","total":105,"occurrence":30}]`

I was able to attain the result in a non functional way, but i would like to optimize code and do it the functional way using lodash as the project is already using it.I was able to find an example where i can groupby on a given column and then use sum operator to aggregate other field. But couldn't find any example to groupby 2 fields and then aggregate. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could group first the items and then map the aggregated values.

```js
var initialArray = [{ date: "2017-07-26", partner: "partner1", total: 102, occurrence: 10 }, { date: "2017-07-27", partner: "partner1", total: 100, occurrence: 20 }, { date: "2017-07-27", partner: "partner1", total: 110, occurrence: 25 }, { date: "2017-07-27", partner: "partner2", total: 105, occurrence: 30 }],
    groups = ['date', 'partner'],
    result = _(initialArray)
        .groupBy(o => groups.map(k => o[k]).join('|'))
        .map((a, k) => ({
            date: a[0].date,
            partner: a[0].partner,
            total: _.sumBy(a, 'total'),
            occurrence: _.sumBy(a, 'occurrence')
        }))
        .value();

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this produces the result you want.

```js
    var a = [   {"date":"2017-07-26","partner":"partner1","total":102,"occurrence":10},
                {"date":"2017-07-27","partner":"partner1","total":100,"occurrence":20},
                {"date":"2017-07-27","partner":"partner1","total":110,"occurrence":25},
                {"date":"2017-07-27","partner":"partner2","total":105,"occurrence":30}
            ];

var out = a.reduce( (s,e,i) => {
    if (i === 0)
        s.push(e);
    else
        if (typeof s.find( ss => ss.date == e.date && ss.partner == e.partner && (ss.total += e.total)) == 'undefined')
            s.push(e);
    return s;
}, []);
    console.log( out );
```